# overflow hidden on safari browser

Tags: javascript, safari, scrollbar, overflow

any other browser does not Show the SVG embedded like shown below with scroll bars. Safari, however does, and it seems like I can't find a way to get rid of em. Any ideeas ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta   http-equiv  ="Content-Type"
            content     ="text/html ; charset = utf-8"/>

    <title>La Bella - Ansbach</title>

    <style>
        html, body { margin : 0 ; padding : 0 ; height : 100% ; width : 100% ;overflow:hidden}
          iframe {overflow:hidden}

    </style>
</head>

<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px; overflow:hidden;">
    <script type    ="text/javascript"  src ="JS/WPL.js"></script>

    <object data    ="default.svg"      src     ="default.svg"
            type    ="image/svg+xml"    id      ="SVG"
            width   ="100%"             height  ="100%"
            scrolling="no"
            style   ="position : absolute ; width : 100% ; height : 100% ; overflow : hidden;overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch">
    </object>
</body>
```

Thx, in advance.